# Принт выводит None вместо настоящего значения. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно чтобы вывело значение rub, но выводит в итоге нан. Я пробовал и просто возвращать, но в цикле иф, не возвращается вообще ничего. А если после него то тоже ничего. Помогите пожалуйста!!
**Код:**

```
from requests import get
def currency_rates(*currency):
    url = 'http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp'
    response = get(url)
    html_words = str(response.content)

    if currency == "usd" or currency == "USD" or currency == "Usd":
        indx_1 = html_words.find("USD")  # 2213
        str_0 = html_words[2213:]
        indx_2 = str_0.find("Value")
        str_1 = str_0[91:95]
        str_1 = str_1.replace(',', '.')
        rub = float(str_1)
        print(rub)
```

Comment: Замените строку `def currency_rates(*currency):` на `def currency_rates(currency):`

Comment: Помогло, но почему?

Comment: потому что `*currency` это кортеж

Comment: и почему из-за этого не сработало?

Comment: потому что в таком случае вы пытаетесь сравнить `('USD',)`  и `'USD'`